# Retrieve Values from Relationship table of has_and_belongs_to_many on Rails5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-5

I have two tables Role and User, and I linked those two tables with has_and_belongs_to_many relationship with rails.

I'm successfully insert the data into the third table which is created by has_and_belongs_to_many relationship. Using the following code

```
def create
user_params[:password] = User.hash(user_params[:password])
@user = User.new(:first_name => user_params[:first_name],
                 :last_name=>user_params[:last_name],
                 :email => user_params[:email],
                 :contact_number=>user_params[:contact_number],
                 :password=>user_params[:password])

@roles = user_params[:roles];
for role in @roles
  @user.roles << Role.find(role)
end
if @user.save
  respond_to do |format|
    msg = { :status => "ok", :message => "User Creation Success!" }
    format.json  { render :json => msg }
  end
end
end
```

Now my problem is how do I read the values from the relationship table and how do I update any value to the relationship table.

Answer (score 1):

Lets suppose you setup your models User Roles like so:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :roles
end

class Role < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :users
end
```

Abd added `users_roles_table`table
You can then retrieve associated data like normal saying

> User.first.roles

and

> Role.first.users